# How to create an scheduled task at startup with the extra condition that no user logins after some specific minutes?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler, idle

I know how to create Windows scheduled tasks that runs after that computer is idle for some minutes/hours. But my question is different.

I want to create a task after startup that computer is idle before a user logins. More precisely, I want to create a task by Windows Task Scheduler that runs at Windows startup with the extra condition that no user logs in after some specific delay (say 7 minutes).